# delete a pair from map in rascal

Tags: rascal

[On this page](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/List/delete/delete.html#/Rascal/Libraries/Prelude/Map/delete/delete.html) in rascal tutor I see a delete function defined on map.

I have the following lines of code:

```
map[loc, list[str]] compareList = ...;
loc f1=..;
compareList = delete(compareList, f1);
```

I get the following error when I run this code: 
"The called signature: delete(map[loc, list[str]], loc),
does not match any of the declared (overloaded) signature patterns:
    list[&T] delete(list[&T], int);
    Condition = delete(Symbol)
    Condition = delete(Symbol)"

Is this a bug in rascal or am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Did you do

```
import Map;
```

?

Looks like it's trying to call delete() on lists, not the delete() on maps.

BTW, this should probably also work:

```
compareList -= (f1 : []);
```